# Executing python code from script and getting interpreter-style output

Tags: python

I need to execute code from my python script and take interpreter-style output like it's done [here](http://pythonregex.com).

I am creating website on GAE using django, it must run user-entered code and print interpreter-style output as text.

Comment: Is there a specific problem that you are having that you need help with?

Comment: What context are you doing this?  From the command line you do `python script >log`.  Are you writing a desktop application, like IDLE?  Are you creating a web site that runs Python code?  What are you talking about?

Comment: I am creating website on GAE using django, it must run dynamic code and print interpreter-style output. How can I take interpreter-style output if I have code in a string form?

Comment: @Dmitry: Do you want to format the code as HTML or text?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic code"?

Comment: @Dmitry Demidenko: Please update your question.  Please.  Please do not add comments to a question which you own.  Please update the question.

Comment: Are you talking about building this?  http://www.datamech.com/devan/trypython/about.html

Comment: Are you talking about this?  http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/getting-started.html

Comment: Please, look at the link inside the question

Comment: @Dmitry Demidenko: The link does not explain what you want to do.  Unless you want to do what the link already does, in which case, why invent something new?  What do *you* want to do?  It's different from that link.  Please update the question with some explanation of what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is `code.InteractiveInterpreter` available, but I think you can take an inspiration in the following simpler example:

```
import code

exprs = [
    'd = {}',
    'd',
    'd["x"] = 1',
    'd',
   ]

for e in exprs:
    print '>>> %s' % e
    cmd = code.compile_command(e)
    r = eval(cmd)
    if r:
        print repr(r)
```

producing the following output:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d
{}
>>> d["x"] = 1
>>> d
{'x': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an open-source console for app engine that does what you want (if I understood the question correctly). Have a look at it: http://con.appspot.com/console/

Instructions to integrate it with your application are available [here](http://con.appspot.com/console/help/integration).